# Can you detect if a textfield has highlighted text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I was wondering if there was a way to detect if a textField.text is currently highlighted.  I am trying to format a phone number, and it works under the exception that the user highlights the field, then starts typing a new number immediately instead of clearing it first.  The first ( does not get set because i try to detect if the field is length 0 before adding it.  On a text highlight, then keypress, the length is larger than 0 so it doesnt work.

thanks

Comment: `UITextField` conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol which provides the `selectedTextRange` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since UITextField (and I believe UITextView) adopt the UITextInput protocol, you can send messages to those with any of that protocols methods, included `selectedTextRange`. See `UITextInput Protocol Reference`.